# $f''(x)$ is always positive then $f(x+f'(x)) \geq f(x) $

Tags: real-analysis, limits, derivatives, continuity

$f: R \to R$ be such that $f''(x) >0$. Prove that $f(x+f'(x)) \geq f(x) $.

My thought: $f''(x) >0$ means f is concave up but $f'(x) $ can be either positive or negative or may be mixed (positive negative both). I am completely confused. Please give some hint.

Comment: Strict inequality is not true. For example, if $f(x)=x^{2}$ then $f(0+f'(0))=f(0)$.

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3538744/42969.

Answer (score 2):

As you recognized that $f(x)$ is a convex function, and it's differentiable. One property we can leverage is that $f(x)$ lives above the tangent line at any point $x$, which is
$$
f(x+t)\geq f(x) + tf'(x),\forall t\in(-\infty,\infty)
$$
Obviously let $t=f'(x)\in(-\infty,\infty)$, the inequality shall still hold.
$$
f(x+f'(x))\geq f(x) + (f'(x))^2\geq f(x)\\
$$

As @Kavi Rama Murthy pointed out when $f'(x)=0$ this inequality is tight.

Answer (score 0):

You have to replace $>$ by $\geq $ as already pointed out.

If $f'(x)$ is never $0$ then it is alwasy positive or always negative (by IVP).  In then first case $f$ is increasing and $x+f'(x) \geq x$ so $f(x+f'(x)) \geq f(x)$. In the second case $f$ is decreasing and $x+f'(x) \leq  x$ so $f(x+f'(x)) \geq f(x)$.

Now suppose $f'(x_0)=0$. Since $f'$ is strictly increasing it follows that $f$ is decreasing in $(-\infty, x_0)$ and increasing in $(x_0,\infty)$. The argument above applies to each of the intervals $(-\infty, x_0)$ and $(x_0,\infty)$ finishing the proof.

Comment: I think your example satisfies the inequality.